# VBA Late Binding for Active DS Type Library

Tags: excel, vba, syntax, active-directory, late-binding

EDIT:
What I have researched on the Active DS Type Library, the examples either require early binding or GetObject.   Can late binding be performed on the Active DS Type library using the CreateObject or does it require GetObject? If it can be called using CreateObject, what is the syntax of the “appname.objecttype” inside?

ORIGINAL: 
I can't seem to find any info on this so I thought I would ask if anyone has a VBA (or similar code) example of using late binding to Active DS Type Library?

What goes inside `CreateObject(<Active DS Syntax here>)`?

Comment: What is your actual issue? Because your issue is X but you ask Y (see [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). • You don't need `CreateObject`. For example to bind a user to an object you can just `Set usr = GetObject("LDAP://CN=jeffsmith,CN=users,DC=fabrikam,DC=com")` that's all.

Comment: That’s all I needed to know.  Thank you!  Here let me update that to provide a better X and Y.

Comment: Wrote it as an anwser so you can accept and close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `CreateObject`.

For example to bind a user to an object you can just

```
Set usr = GetObject("LDAP://CN=jeffsmith,CN=users,DC=fabrikam,DC=com")
```

that's all. For more info see the documentation of the [GetObject function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getobject-function).

Comment: Thank you for the info.  Much appreciated.